# Tables not visible in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to try and see the data I'm importing into a local database, but there are no tables listed. I've successfully created the tables and imported data into them, but I cannot see them in the Object Explorer. Even refreshing doesn't work. I'm positive the data is there, as I get a primary key restraint when adding the data again, and can successfully pull data out. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is Your role on server and database?

Comment: i experienced same issue when my table name consisted of spaces,some body edited mistakenly